# This code that is supposed to get the largest and average of input numbers is not giving me the desired output, what did I get wrong?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to get this code to give me an output of "20 9.50" when I input "15 20 0 3 -1" but it keeps giving me the output "20 0.55". This is the code I've made:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   int largest = 0;
   int number = 0;
   int count = 0;
   double avg = 0;
   
   while (number >= 0) {
      cin >> number;
      if (number >= 0) {
         if (number > largest) {
            largest = number;
         }
         avg += number; ++count;
      }
      if (count > 0) {
         avg /= count;
      }
   }
   cout << largest << " " << fixed << setprecision(2) << avg << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone point out how I'm getting the wrong output? I'm in a class for C++ but I'm still new to it. Hopefully I'm not treated too harshly, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try debugging it?  At what point do things go wrong?  HINT:  debug and watch the value of `avg` on each iteration of your loop and see if it matches your expectations.

Comment: You are doing `avg /= count;` more then once! Also you have to many `if`s.

Comment: @MarekR: An you have too few `o`'s. (Just trying to salvage some dignity here ;-) )

Comment: Good approach, doing the analysis on the fly instead of reading everything into a vector and analyzing it afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you are supposed to maintain the average "on the fly".

The better, less error-prone, approach is to maintain a total for the life of the loop. Then, after the `while` loop, you should average by dividing the `total` by the `count`.

FYI, for everyone else: **The -1 ends the `while` loop** and **`total` & `count` should not include the -1 at the ending of every input.**

The following code gives output of `20 9.50` with input of `15 20 0 3 -1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   int largest = 0;
   int number = 0;
   int count = 0;
   double avg = 0;
   double total = 0;

   while (number >= 0) {
      cin >> number;
      if (number >= 0) {
         if (number > largest) {
            largest = number;
         }
         //avg += number; ++count;
         total += number; ++count;
      }
      //if (count > 0) {
      //   avg /= count;
   }
   
   avg = total / count;
   cout << largest << " " << fixed << setprecision(2) << avg << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes this code works for me

Comment: Just make sure to check that `count > 0` before dividing `total / count`, otherwise you will get *undefined behavior*. Also, the `while` loop can be simplified to `while (cin >> number && number >= 0) { ... }` It doesn't make sense to check `number >= 0` before the 1st `cin >> number` is executed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Interesting to put the cin in the while loop. I left out an if statement containing `count > 0` before dividing `total / count` because the user might input no numbers and want to see an input of `0 0.00` which is technically correct. If we put that if statement, we would just get back 0 which does not fit the requirements i.e return average and max number

Comment: If the user enters no numbers at all, or enters a negative number as the 1st input, then `count` will be `0`, making `total / count` cause *undefined behavior*, so you need to guard against that. You can't divide by `0`. With a guarding `if` in place, you can still output `0 0.00` since `largest` and `avg` are initialized to `0`. The *output* does not need to be inside an `if`, only the *division*.

Comment: This was perfect, thanks for the corrections!

Answer (score 0):

You divide avg by count several times.
But you must do it one more after cycle

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int largest = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double avg = 0;

    while (number >= 0) {
        cin >> number;
        if (number >= 0) {
            if (number > largest) {
                largest = number;
            }
            avg += number; ++count;
        }
        
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        avg /= count;
    }
    cout << largest << " " << fixed << setprecision(2) << avg << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The usage of `avg` for a variable name is not correct – you are using it as a total – and then dividing it to get the average. The better approach is to make it a different variable.

Comment: yes, and if (number >= 0) isn't good idea. I wanted to show the author how to change his code